# downloading a file directly to the hard drive

Tags: javascript, html, css, download

Can anyone provide an html code, js, or css script that creates a link that downloads a specified file to the hard drive (to what ever subdirectory some one has specified for their downloaded files)? I would be happy to be directed to a URL where the code or script is already displayed.

Comment: What have you tried? We are willing to help you with your code, but we are not slaves.

Comment: I consider myself quite familiar with html, moderately familiar with javascript, and css, so I have tried with my level of skill on all three. I have succeeded with links that download to the browser. The files I need to have potential buyers of my book download are 30-40 MB book samples. That isn't going to work well sending the files to the browser. Sorry, I didn't consider anyone here a slave.

Answer (score -1):

Just link to the file using the anchor tag  and the href attribute.

```
<a href="somefile_on_the_server.pdf">Some clickable text</a>
```

Just google it up on google it a basic HTML element.